# Is there a way to get time since insert of an event in NEsper?

Tags: esper, epl

I'm trying to use NEsper and I want to create statements that takes time since insert as a return field.

ex:
select avg((insertTime - now)) as timeElapsed
from Blah.win:time(1 min)

Is this possible? I can hack around getting insertTime but is there a now function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use current_timestamp. It returns the current time in milliseconds. 
For example  `select avg((insertTime - current_timestamp))`

See there for more information: http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-2.1.0/doc/reference/en/html/functionreference.html